# Can't stop my custom clock

Tags: java

I've created class called Clock:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

  public class Clock {

    private int seconds;
    private int minutes;
    private int hours;
    private String printableSeconds;
    private String printableMinutes;
    private String printableHours;
    public boolean shouldStop;
    public Clock() {}
    public void start() {
        shouldStop = false;
        while (shouldStop == false) {
            wait(1000);
            icrementSeconds();
            printableSeconds = "" + seconds;
            if (seconds < 10) addZeroBeforeSeconds();
            printableMinutes = "" + minutes;
            if (minutes < 10) addZeroBeforeMinutes();
            printableHours = "" + hours;
            if (hours < 10) addZeroBeforeHours();
            if (seconds == 60) {
                icrementMinutes();
            }
            if (minutes == 60) {
                icrementHours();
            }
            printTime();
            System.out.println(shouldStop);
        }
    }
    public void stop() {
        shouldStop = true;
    }
    public void reset() {
        System.out.println("RESETING");
        seconds = 0;
        minutes = 0;
        hours = 0;
    }
    private void wait(int ms) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
    private void addZeroBeforeSeconds() {
        printableSeconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    private void addZeroBeforeMinutes() {
        printableMinutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    private void addZeroBeforeHours() {
        printableHours = "0" + hours;
    }
    private void icrementSeconds() {
        seconds++;
    }
    private void icrementMinutes() {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
    }
    private void icrementHours() {
        minutes = 0;
        hours++;
    }
    private void printTime() {
        System.out.println(printableHours + ":" + printableMinutes + ":" + printableSeconds);
    }
 }
```

In my `Main` class i call `clock.start()` and it is working fine, but when i want to stop printing time, I'm just not able to to that.I assume that the problem is that while loop inside `start()` method.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Clock clock = new Clock();
         clock.start();

         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         int a = input.nextInt();

            if(a==1)
            clock.stop();

    }

}
```

For example i want to stop the clock by pressing 1. `reset()` method doesn't work neither.

Comment: this can't work you're setting the shouldStop boolean to false and next time you call .stop() you set it to true. but like that it won't get evaluated in your while loop therefore your loop runs infinitely

Comment: yeah i know,but what can i do to make this work?

Comment: you are calling clock.start() in current thread which is entering a loop. You will never get out of that loop and you statements after calling clock.start() will never get executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reset()` method does probably work, but in your current code, it will never reach the

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Line, because you are first calling the `clock.start();` method which has an infinite loop. So once that loop quits, then you are able to call for user input.

The solution for this is to create a thread. in your thread, call `clock.start();` and now your `main` method will continue to execute, so now you can ask for user input and call `clock.stop();`.

Some example code (written by hand an not tested):

```
public class Clock implements Runnable{

    private int seconds;
    private int minutes;
    private int hours;
    private String printableSeconds;
    private String printableMinutes;
    private String printableHours;
    public boolean shouldStop;
    public Clock() {}

    public void run() {   // Notice how I changed this to run
        shouldStop = false;
        while (shouldStop == false) {
            wait(1000);
            icrementSeconds();
            printableSeconds = "" + seconds;
            if (seconds < 10) addZeroBeforeSeconds();
            printableMinutes = "" + minutes;
            if (minutes < 10) addZeroBeforeMinutes();
            printableHours = "" + hours;
            if (hours < 10) addZeroBeforeHours();
            if (seconds == 60) {
                icrementMinutes();
            }
            if (minutes == 60) {
                icrementHours();
            }
            printTime();
            System.out.println(shouldStop);
        }
    }
    public void stop() {
        shouldStop = true;
    }

    //yourcode
}
```

And in `main()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Clock clock = new Clock();
    Thread th = new Thread(clock);
    th.start();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = input.nextInt();

    if(a==1)
        clock.stop();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Clock` class is fine you need to use `Thread` in `main` method like this

```
  final Clock clock = new Clock();

  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        clock.start();
    }
  });

  t.start();

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int a = input.nextInt();

  if(a==1){
     t.stop();
  }
```

cheers!